# Encoding key-value pairs in an RSS feed's URL

Tags: web-services, http, rss

I've noticed that most websites don't set up their RSS feed URLs to make use of encoded key-value pairs that let one create specific queries, like the following fictional example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds?tag=python&lang=en&minvotes=2
```

Is there a particular technical reason for this? Or am I just not finding the RSS feeds that do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical reason.  My company does this now with our news feeds.

I'd post a link, but it requires registration to see the feeds.  We have urls like `.../feed.php?type=news`, etc.